# Glueing tile images together using imagemagick's montage command without resizing

Tags: image, imagemagick, tiles

This seems like it might be a reasonably common question, so I'm going to ask it using as many keywords as I can think of!

I have a bunch of (well, nine) tile jpegs, with standard tile filenames. Each jpeg is 220x175 pixels:

```
(top row)
tile_1_0_0.jpg
tile_1_1_0.jpg
tile_1_2_0.jpg
(middle row)
tile_1_0_1.jpg
tile_1_1_1.jpg
tile_1_2_1.jpg
(bottom row)
tile_1_0_2.jpg
tile_1_1_2.jpg
tile_1_2_2.jpg
```

How can I use imagemagick/montage to 'glue' or join them all together to make a single, coherent image? I don't want to resize them at all, so I guess the final image should be 660x525.

That would be montage with no framing, shadowing, bordering, etc - just the nine original images, glued together to make a single jpeg.

I know it should be something along these lines, but I'm struggling with getting the order and sizing right:

```
montage +frame +shadow +label -tile 3x3 -geometry <options> *.jpg joined.jpg
```

Comment: Also possibly related: [remove extra tilespace from a montage (ImageMagick) composite image? - Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4046/remove-extra-tilespace-from-a-montage-imagemagick-composite-image/63463#63463)

Answer (score 45):

I was looking to do something similar and ended up here (I guess your "as many keywords as possible" thing worked). Here's what I came up with that worked for me. (geometry and tile adjusted for your needs)

```
montage -border 0 -geometry 660x -tile 3x3 tile* final.jpg
```

The files get added to the tiles horizontally, so, for `-tile 4x2`, the disposition would be:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

The numbers being the relative positions of the filenames in the argument list.

As far as I can tell, `tile*` will expand alphabetically, so you should either specify your filenames manually, or rename then so that they'll sort appropriately, e.g.:

```
# top row
tile_r0_c0.jpg
tile_r0_c1.jpg
tile_r0_c2.jpg
# middle row
tile_r1_c0.jpg
tile_r1_c1.jpg
tile_r1_c2.jpg
# bottom row
tile_r2_c0.jpg
tile_r2_c1.jpg
tile_r2_c2.jpg
```

Comment: I assumed `660x` was the final size (3 images @ 220px each). From reading [the example](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#geometry_size), I think the `-geometry` flag resizes *each* image to this size (thus, using `-geometry 220x` would maintain the original size in this case). Does that seem correct?

Comment: `geometry` can either control a tiling border (`+w+h` option) and final size of the figure (`WxH`). However, the output will be resized if you don't add at least  `+0+0` (see my full command below)

Answer (score 39):

Dave's solution didn't work for me, so I found a better answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/290656/combine-multiple-images-using-imagemagick). Try this:

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile 3x3 tile*.jpg result.jpg
```

it also works without the second "3"

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile 3x tile*.jpg result.jpg
```

the complete line for Windows users is:

```
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\montage.exe" -mode concatenate -tile 3x tile*.jpg result.jpg
```

(change the "6.8.0-Q16" with your own version of ImageMagick, of course)

Comment: I have install ImageMagick on Windows but i don't see montage.exe file

Comment: Be sure to check the ImageMagick installer option "Install legacy utilities (e.g. convert)". (tested with version 7.0.7)

Comment: @JohnDoe Since v7, `montage ...` has become `magick montage ...`

Answer (score 4):

I personally use this minimal command for such tasks:

```
montage tile*.jpg -tile 3x3 -geometry +0+0 output.jpg
```

`geometry +0+0` will not add any border and conserve the original size of each image (a very much advised option).