# Many bmp files to one file

Tags: bmp

I got 7000 bmp files and each file is 1kb big with a single letter in it (ascii-code).
I have no idea how to open them all together.
I tried pdf printers but I can't print the bmp files because the printers say they are broken. I can open the files with "irfanview" but only 1 file after another and not together.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question. What type of answer are you looking for? If you aren't trying to use code to do this then Stack Overflow isn't the correct place for this question.

Comment: Possibly [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853334/glueing-tile-images-together-using-imagemagicks-montage-command) about using the montage program.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the images are of a fixed size, here's some psuedocode you can use in something like C# to open and display all the images:

1. Create a canvas whose size is the width of 100X width and 70X height of an image.
2. Loop through each image:
3. Open image, draw to canvas based on index.
4. Print your canvas to screen, printer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a mac user,Use python plot to display all images in terminal